# Displaying Garbage Characters in Bootloader Output

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader

I'm trying to write a small bootloader for a small OS I'm working on. The primary MBR bootloader is working just fine, but the secondary one have a strange appearance behavior - it display garbage on the screen along with "Starting the operating system..." message or completely masks the message with garbage. That garbage is probably from the RAM. I suspect there's something wrong with how my registers are handled and how data is read from them. So, what's the issue here? I would really appreciate a reply!

1. I wiped the entire disk in an attempt to remove orphaned garbage data from it - reduced the garbage issue to some extent
2. The bootloader now prints "Starting the operating system..." correctly, but also display "¦", which have nothing to do with the source code and which is likely garbage.

P.S: I'm testing the bootloader on a QEMU virtual machine (ofc I'm not crazy to test it on a real machine)

```
ORG 0x8000

BITS 16

section .text

    global start

start:

    mov ah, 0x00

    mov al, 0x03

    int 0x10

    mov si, starting_message

    call print

    mov ax, 0x07C0

    mov ds, ax

    mov es, ax

    mov ah, 0x02

    mov al, 0x01

    mov ch, 0x00

    mov dh, 0x00

    mov dl, 0x80

    mov bx, buffer

    int 0x13

    jc error_missing_pit

    xor cx, cx

    mov si, buffer

loop:

    mov ax, [si + 0x1C]

    test ax, ax

    jnz found_bootable

    add si, 16

    inc cx

    cmp cx, 0

    jz no_bootable

    jmp loop

found_bootable:

    mov di, pit_info

    mov cx, 16

    rep movsb

    mov ax, [si + 0x08]

    mov [active_partition_info], ax

    mov ax, [si + 0x0C]

    mov [active_partition_info + 2], ax

    jmp kernel_load

error_missing_pit:

    mov si, missing_pit

    call print

    cli

    hlt

no_bootable:

    mov si, no_partition

    call print

    cli

    hlt

section .data

    buffer db 16 dup(0)

    pit_info db 16 dup(0)

    active_partition_info dw 0

starting_message:

    db "Starting the operating system...", 0x0A, 0

missing_pit: 

     db "Partition Table error!", 0x0A, 0

no_partition:

     db "Kernel partition cannot be found - does it have the active flag?", 0x0A, 0

print:

    mov bx, 0

    call print_loop

    ret

print_loop:

    mov al, [si] 

    cmp al, 0 

    je print_done 

    mov ah, 0x0E 

    int 0x10 

    inc si 

    jmp print_loop

print_done:

    ret

kernel_load:

;.....................
```

Comment: `ah = 02h, int 13h` reads 512 bytes to `buffer`, which size is 16 bytes. `cl` should contain number of starting sector.

Comment: `ORG 0x8000` is very suspicious in conjunction with `mov ax, 0x07C0; mov ds, ax`

Comment: Hmmm, is `section .data` in good place? I mean if program reads sector it will override everything what is after buffer.

Comment: Michael Petch's [general tips for bootloader development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32701854/boot-loader-doesnt-jump-to-kernel-code) are probably worth reading.   Also [whats the use of "org xxxx" in assembly for a legacy PC BIOS MBR bootloader?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10301467) is probably relevant for the `org` that doesn't match the way you set `DS`; that's why `mov si, starting_message` doesn't assemble to an offset that corresponds to where the `starting_message:` label is in memory

Comment: @Jester Thanks. I modified the code to ax, 0x8000 and moved the data section to the top. Now everything works as intented.

Comment: @Nassau Thanks. I have moved the data section to the top and the code now behaves as intented.